# Firebase Alert subscriptions: no Crashlytics settings

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to setup email notifications for crash reports, but when I go to project alert settings I don't see crashlytics settings (but Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore are visible), I have owner permission.
Where can I enable crashlytics settings ?

Answer (score -1):

You can check the following document:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/velocity-alerts

> Receive alerts
> You can route velocity alerts to your team using either:
>
> Emails — configure in your Firebase alert subscriptions for Crashlytics via Alerts > Alert Settings.
>
> Integrations (such as Slack, Jira, or PagerDuty) — configure via Firebase Project Settings > Integrations.

Comment: Thank you, read this document, but it didn't help to make email alerts for Crashlytics settings visible

Comment: Hi @MariaTaggart did you solve your issue. Appreciates your guidance .